# Postgresql - select something where date = "01/01/11"

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a datetime field in my Postgresql, named "dt".
I'd like to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE extract (date from dt) = '01/01/11'
```

What is the right syntax to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 158, accepted):

I think you want to cast your `dt` to a `date` and fix [the format of your date literal](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE dt::date = '2011-01-01' -- This should be ISO-8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD
```

Or the [standard version](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CAST(dt AS DATE) = '2011-01-01' -- This should be ISO-8601 format, YYYY-MM-DD
```

The [`extract` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) doesn't understand "date" and it returns a number.

Comment: One addition:  If the timestamp field is indexed, using dt::date or CAST(dt AS date) prevents the index from being used.  An alternate method would be to either build a functional index on dt::date or to write it this way (using parameter $1 as a date string): WHERE dt >= $1 AND dt < $1 + interval '1 day'.

Comment: whatever @MatthewWood says, is always right :)

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 18):

With PostgreSQL there are a number of date/time functions available, see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

In your example, you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_trunc('day', dt) = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

If you are running this query regularly, it is possible to create an index using the `date_trunc` function as well:

```
CREATE INDEX date_trunc_dt_idx ON myTable ( date_trunc('day', dt) );
```

One advantage of this is there is some more flexibility with timezones if required, for example:

```
CREATE INDEX date_trunc_dt_idx ON myTable ( date_trunc('day', dt at time zone 'Australia/Sydney') );
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_trunc('day', dt at time zone 'Australia/Sydney') = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```