# I want to search something only datewise without time stamp in

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql

I want to search something only datewise without time stamp in Postgres DB.

Comment: Please include sample data and your SQL code.

Comment: What you a tried so far?

Comment: you search like datewise means Please give some sample data

otherwise please check  the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875712/postgresql-select-something-where-date-01-01-11

Comment: like this is the data  surname             |creationdate|creationtime
> --------------------+------------+------------
> Name_3              |  22.03.1999|06:02:55
> Name_2              |  29.03.1999|09:10:04 and when m searching by date wise only, not getting nothing....and when m placing exact date and time stamp, giving output. As i am not aware about exact time only aware about date.

Comment: MSISDN PROCESS_TIMESTAMP
x 12/23/17 1:56
y  1/10/2018 2:45
z 10/20/2017 21:13
a 12/31/2017 11:28
u 12/22/2017 3:33

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tble WHERE date(date) = '2017-01-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date::date = '2021-02-09'
```

Answer (score -1):

Select The Date in  query and use % after ex.

```
Select * from tble Where date LIKE '2017-01-10%'
```

Comment: select * from RENEWAL where PROCESS_TIMESTAMP = '2017-04-10 %';
Empty set (4.84 sec)

Comment: PROCESSING_STATE | PROCESS_TIMESTAMP  

-----------------+--------------------

               0 | 2016-03-26 02:33:21

               0 | 2015-09-20 02:29:31

               0 | 2016-10-17 02:27:46

               0 | 2017-04-10 02:11:22

               0 | 2016-08-29 02:33:03

Comment: i made changes in query try now

Comment: Yes. It is running. Thank you so much Rohit JI

Answer (score -1):

select * from table 
where trunc(date) = to_Date(;01/01/2018','mm/dd/yyyy')

Comment: not running scs=# select * from fdp_user_bkp where trunc(registration_dt) = to_Date(;2013-08-28','mm/dd/yyyy')
scs'#